# generate a DynamoDB put_item with multiple keys

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am following [this tuto](https://www.acloudpage.com/2019/02/27/load-csv-to-aws-dynamodb/). I need to do the same with a csv that contains 120 columns.
In the tuto, Keys for items are given manually. Is there any way to do that automatically? I already have a list with the csv columns that I can use. All of my columns are Strings. This is the block I want to automatize:

```
response = dyndb.put_item(
                TableName='emplist',
                Item={
                'empid' : {'N':str(empid)},
                'name': {'S':name},
                'salary': {'N':str(salary)},
                'parttime': {'BOOL':False},
                }
            )
```

My column names list is:

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as the types can differ, it is best do it manually for some columns. Check which one is predominant, automate that and do manually the rest.

Let's assume 'S' is found in ~90 columns.

```
for index, row_item in enumerate(row):
    items_dict['column_' + i] = {'S': row_item}

# now manually replace the ones with a different type or that have additional parsing
item_dict['column_4'] = {'N': int(row[4])}
...

# if you want different key names do:
item_dict['name'] = item_dict['column_5']
del item_dict['column_5']

response = dyndb.put_item(
            TableName='emplist',
            Item=item_dict
        )
```

Comment: As I said in my question, all of my types are String. I don't need different names. What does the column_+i do?

Comment: missed that, but the code sample is good for further reference. You need to have a key name for each dynamically generated column, right?

Comment: I was maybe not so clear. Sorry. I only need to insert my CSV file into a DynamboDB table. columns in the CSV are the columns in the table without any transformation. My problem was that I have a lot of columns so I can't write them manually one by one as in the link. I think the for loop in your solution should correct that. No?

Comment: the `for` should do just that

Comment: Should I put it Inside the for in the example?

Comment: And isn't not missing item_dict={} somewhere ?

Comment: yes, the sample is just to get you on the right track :) not having your full code, requirements and environment, makes it difficult to actually test and include everything